# Customize what fields show on Views Exposed Filters Block

Tags: views

I have configured an exposed form block, filtering by taxonomy list. What I need to do is simply display a field image before the taxonomy name. The actual display is  `<Taxonomy Term Name>` and what I need is `<Taxonomy Term Logo> <Taxonomy Term Image>`. I have looked on some places, but I couldn't get anything to work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply rearrange the fields i.e. put field image before the taxonomy name. You can get the rearrange button at right side of **FIELDS** in view configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `drop-down option` just after the `add field option` you can see the `re-arrange option` from there you can arrange the fields according to you.